# Pyqt QGraphicView mouse coordinate system

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to crop an image with a Qgraphicview
But I am facing an offset issue
Here's the QMainWindow

```
class ImageViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.cropLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.imageLabel)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.scene.addWidget(splitter)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
```

...

```
def mousePressEvent(self, eventQMouseEvent):
    print("pressed")
    self.originQPoint = self.view.mapToScene(eventQMouseEvent.pos())
    self.currentQRubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
    self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
    self.currentQRubberBand.show()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, eventQMouseEvent):
    self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
    #self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
    currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
    print(currentQRect)
    self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
    cropPixmap = self.pixmap.copy(currentQRect)
    self.cropLabel.setPixmap(cropPixmap)
    cropPixmap.save('output.png')
```

The code works good but I have an offset (seems to be margin or menubar value or a mix). So I guess I am not in the good system but do not know how to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I left QGraphicView and reimplemented the mouse event in a dedicated Widget class that handle the QLabel.
I's working good

```
class View(QtWidgets.QLabel):
def __init__(self):
    super(View,self).__init__()

    self.cropLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

    self.ogpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    fileName = r'C:/Users/user11.HPO-SAMAT/Pictures/Lake.jpg'
    image = QtGui.QImage(fileName)
    self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.label.adjustSize()

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.originQPoint = event.pos()
    self.currentQRubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
    self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
    self.currentQRubberBand.show()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint, event.pos()).normalized())

def mouseReleaseEvent (self, event):
    self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
    currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
    self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
    cropPixmap = self.pixmap.copy(currentQRect)
    self.cropLabel.setPixmap(cropPixmap)

class Viewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.view = View()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
```